# Update AMI American Megatrends BIOS via EFI/UEFI firmware shell

Tags: bios, uefi, efi, flashing

I have found an used gigabyte brixx nuc style pc and wanted to try to update it's bios for testing, because some other versions has been released. The device hasn't a direct flash utility inside so I have to resort to an external tool.

On the gigabyte website the bios image is provided but it says "**Please download BIOS update tool from AMI Website**" and links to: https://www.ami.com/support-other/

Now.. it isn't wrote what kind of tool I have to pick.

I tried on a Windows 10 machine to run all the provided softwares

- the amibios8 doesn't work at all telling that the driver isn't found, basically because is a 32bit driver that doesn't work on win10x64.
- the x64 version of aptio4 runs but says that isn't the right tool and tells to use aptio5.
- the x64 version of aptio5 silently quits without showing any window.

The aptio5 directory contains also a Afuefi folder that should be an utility able to update the bios directly from efi shell. The folder contains 32, 64 and aarch64. My guess is that aarch64 is itanium and 64 is amd64 so I should need the 64 folder.

I've also found this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=citN29QZ4xs

Do any of you used efi to flash the bios? I seem to be unable to do it under windows, and getting a genuine copy of dos without mess seems to be difficult, should I go with efi ? It is reliable?

How to understand if my motherboard is compatible with afuefi and which version of the flasher?
Maybe I could try to save the current bios and see if everything works correctly and assuming the fact that the rom is saved good enough to go for the flashing?

**bonus: what command line I should use? I'm confused by all that bios parts that are now present in uefi environments, I was used to just flash the whole bios**

Comment: I had American Megatrends on my prior desktop machine. I used the Manufacturer's BIOS update package to update the UEFI BIOS. That worked very well.

Comment: If you have access to an OS then use a tool like Specify and provide the motherboard model number and revision.

Comment: Depending on age, the UEFI interface can have a BIOS upload utility built in and requires no external tool. In any case, need the model number of the mobo.

Comment: All my machines (including this one built in 2023) use a file from the Manufacturer to update UEFI BiOS outside the OS.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I managed to update all BIOS of my machines by using the manifacturer original zip file.

Once extracted there are various files, fun part they changed the name of the main executable that had to be run via EFI with a less obviousy one and also added a **FLASH.NSH** file **where .NSH are the EFI equivalents of .BAT in Windows and .SH in Linux**.

So here's the procedure: unzip the ZIP content and put it in a flash drive, at the startup go in BIOS settings and select **"Boot EFI shell"**, when the boot is complete go inside the flash drive content with cd fd0 or similar command where fd0 is your flash drive.
At this point I first used the utility provided to do a backup copy of the current BIOS and then ran the FLASH.NSH file, then reboot and remove the external flash drive.